# How to combine data preprocessing code within tflite model (Integrate data preprocessing code within tflite)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-serving

I am having a SAVED_MODEL_PATH that contains assets, variables and saved_model.pb

SAVED_MODEL_PATH

- assets
- variables
- saved_model.pb

### I can convert this into tflite model using the below code (Main Part)

```
# Convert the model
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(SAVED_MODEL_PATH)
 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
 
tflite_model_name = 'model.tflite'
# Save the model.
with open(tflite_model_name, 'wb') as f:
 f.write(tflite_model)
```

Now while using an interpreter I need to convert images of any size to the requirement of my model. For example, my existing model required an image of 320 x 320 then

### reading an image

```
img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
image_np = np.array(img)
```

### preprocessing code (need to combine this code with tflite model)

```
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
input_data = tf.reshape(tf.image.resize(image_np, [320, 320]), [1, 320, 320, 3])
```

### inputting preprocessed data into interpreter

```
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
[[[0.05000001 0.55       0.85       0.95      ]
[0.17500001 0.12500003 0.375      0.5250001 ]
[0.5375     0.5375     0.7375001  0.6374999 ]
[0.6875     0.7625     0.7875     0.96250004]
[0.86249995 0.33749998 1.0625     0.4375    ]
[0.46678936 0.26678932 0.6082107  0.40821064]
[0.53357863 0.7335787  0.8164213  1.0164213 ]
[0.2125     0.7375     0.4125     0.83750004]
[0.61678934 0.66678935 0.75821066 0.8082107 ]
[0.29178935 0.86678934 0.43321067 1.0082107 ]]]
```

Now is there any way to call any code that is performing preprocessing to an image to include in tflite model so that when it encounters an image it does the preprocessing (any kind of transformation that might include creation of custom transformation function ? )
For example, if we resize an image of any size (in this case) it can directly convert the image to the required size (320 x 320 or any other size based on requirement)?

Comment: As mentioned by @sakumoil, you can add a `Resizing` layer to your existing model to resize the inputs given a fixed shape.

Comment: That can be added during training but here I want to integrate once we already have tflite model in place.  Also normalization is one part, I want to be flexible about custom transformation. Hope you got the idea

Comment: I hope my edited answer is able to help.

Comment: I think you are asking for TFLite Support library or Task library with ImageProcessor(you have to add metadata to the .tflite file). Check documantation
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support and https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/overview

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras.layers.Resizing` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Resizing) could be used in your model.

Edit:
Updating the answer:

You can train the model regularly, and after training and converting to TFLite you can add the preprocessing layers to the beginning of the model.

First, let's create a dummy model:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, 1, 'same'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, 1, 'same')
    ]
)

model.build(input_shape=(1, 64, 64, 3))
model.summary()
```

```sh
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (1, 64, 64, 32)         896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (1, 64, 64, 32)         9248      
=================================================================
Total params: 10,144
Trainable params: 10,144
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Next, we add the resizing layer to the model and print `summary` again:

```py
model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Resizing(64, 64),
        model
    ]
)

model2.build(input_shape=(1, 128, 128, 3))
model2.summary()
```

```sh
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resizing (Resizing)          (1, 64, 64, 3)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential (Sequential)      (1, 64, 64, 32)           10144     
=================================================================
Total params: 10,144
Trainable params: 10,144
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Then we can convert the model to `TFLite` and visualize it:

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model2)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("test.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

[image]

Now we have a TFLite model where the preprocessing layers have been added after the training of the model.

Comment: Thanks @sakumoil . However, it is only solving how to add image resizing thing into the pipeline. I am looking to put any transformation function in the model.

Comment: Tensorflow Keras also has other transformation layers, such as [rescaling](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Rescaling), [reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape), [normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization), [padding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D). Hopefully some of these could be of use.